# App crash every time i run it on my phone

Tags: android, media-player

I want to make a universal soundboard.
But it won't run, that is strange while i don't have any errors.
I searched online for a solution but i can't find it.
This is the code i used:

```
package com.soundboard;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Soundboard extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
Resources res = getResources();
int[] buttonIds = {R.id.sound1,R.id.sound2,R.id.sound3,R.id.sound4,R.id.sound5,R.id.sound6,R.id.sound7,R.id.sound8,R.id.sound9,R.id.sound10,R.id.sound11,R.id.sound12,R.id.sound13,R.id.sound14,R.id.sound15,R.id.sound16};
int[] soundIds = {R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3, R.raw.sound4, R.raw.sound5, R.raw.sound6, R.raw.sound7, R.raw.sound8, R.raw.sound9, R.raw.sound10, R.raw.sound11, R.raw.sound12, R.raw.sound13, R.raw.sound14, R.raw.sound15, R.raw.sound16};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main); 
} 

public void onClick(View v) {
    //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
    //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
    //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                try {
                    player.reset();
                    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();
                    afd.close();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks,
Flow

Comment: please post the stacktrace associated with the error. The stacktrace can be found using Logcat.

Comment: sounds great. implementing onClickListner and not setting onclicklistner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you didn'yt set the onclickListener on the View you are clicking.
I think the view is a button. call setOnclickListener() on the button in the javacode.